# jQuery SlideDown() is not waiting for delay on animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use jQuery function that should animate divs (Slide down and up) like a dynamic menu or something.

The problem is even I set up delay() - when mouse goes over it, no matter how long the cursor stays over one div it will slidewon and up.

To clarify. If I put a mouse over the certain div, it works well, it waits the delay and then slide. But if I fast goes over all divs in the example it will make a weird reaction, like the divs start to slide down but then suddenly stops and go up. Try my fiddle and you'll see.

This is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GzxJf/7/)

```
jQuery(".subdiv").hide();

jQuery(".mydiv").hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).find(".subdiv").stop().delay(800).slideDown("slow");
}, function(){
    jQuery(this).find(".subdiv").stop().delay(200).slideUp("slow");
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GzxJf/8/

Comment: Unbelievable. Thank you mate. Still a bebginner

Answer (score 0):

So something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/GzxJf/12/

```
jQuery(".subdiv").hide();

jQuery(".mydiv").hover(function(){
    jQuery(".subdiv").each(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).attr('display') !== "none") {
            jQuery(this).stop(true).slideUp("slow");
        }
    });
    jQuery(this).find(".subdiv").slideDown("slow");
}, function(){
    jQuery(this).find(".subdiv").slideUp("slow");
});
```